# Unit Tests using MassTransit Test Harness randomly fail on build server

Tags: c#, testing, masstransit

I wrote some test with the following structure using the TestHarness:

```cs
using MassTransit.Testing;

namespace g2fp.PosApi.UnitTests;

public class SampleTest : IAsyncLifetime
{
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
        
        serviceCollection.AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumer<SomeConsumer>();
        });

        Services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        Harness = Services.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
        ConsumerHarness = Services.GetRequiredService<IConsumerTestHarness<SomeConsumer>>();

        await Harness.Start();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Consume()
    {
        await Harness.Bus.Publish(new SomeMessage("something"));
        // await Harness.InactivityTask;
        (await Harness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SomeMessage>().Any()).Should().BeTrue();
        (await ConsumerHarness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SomeMessage>().Any()).Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public IConsumerTestHarness<SomeConsumer> ConsumerHarness { get; set; }

    public ITestHarness Harness { get; set; }

    public ServiceProvider Services { get; set; }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await Harness.Stop();
    }
}

public record SomeMessage(string Message);

public class SomeConsumer : IConsumer<SomeMessage>
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public SomeConsumer(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SomeMessage> context)
    {
        await _someService.DoSomething();
    }
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    Task DoSomething();
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

On my PC I can run this test 1000 times and it's fine, but on our pipeline (Gitlab) from time to time it fails on the following line:

`(await Harness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SomeMessage>().Any()).Should().BeTrue();`

It doesn't really matter how much delay I put in `SomeService` - the test waits nicely for that to finish, so that we can do asserts on our mocks.

Am I missing something obvious or is it just flaky? When the test fails, execution time is around 2s, so I guess that the wait logic in `Harness.Consumed` actually waits, but nothing happens.

Should I change the order of waiting? Should I do something like:

```cs
var waitTask = Harness.Consumed.SelectAsync<SomeMessage>().Any();
await Harness.Bus.Publish(new SomeMessage("something"));
await waitTask).Should().BeTrue();
```

It still works, but I have no idea if that is less flaky or not. Maybe the classic `ConfigureAwait` in some place would unlock writing to consumed message collection?

---

EDIT: Following the advice, I set the inactivity timeout to 10s:

```cs
 serviceCollection.AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.SetTestTimeouts(testInactivityTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            ConfigureTestHarness(cfg);
        });
```

However, the test still fails randomly, in the same way as before, without waiting for the full timeout span.

Here are the logs with timestamps, and you can see logs from the actuall consumer (I changed the names, so if there is something incosistent, it's due to that):

```
 2023-06-06T09:30:35.5251966+00:00 - Information - 0 - MassTransit - Configured endpoint my-message-endpoint, Consumer: MyConsumer
 2023-06-06T09:30:35.5270254+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Transports.BusDepot - Starting bus instances: IBus
 2023-06-06T09:30:35.5270426+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Starting bus: loopback://localhost/
 2023-06-06T09:30:39.5021627+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/my-message-endpoint
 2023-06-06T09:30:39.5049111+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/runnerwspzdzwlproject21928941concurrent0_testhost_bus_9hboyyfcnrbrfprdbdpschfqfb
 2023-06-06T09:30:39.5050096+00:00 - Information - 0 - MassTransit - Bus started: loopback://localhost/
 2023-06-06T09:30:39.5363258+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Create send transport: loopback://localhost/urn:message:MyMessage
 2023-06-06T09:30:39.5365853+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Messages - SEND loopback://localhost/urn:message:Events:MyMessage ff030000-ac11-0242-a321-08db6670b105 Events.MyMessage
 2023-06-06T09:30:41.6678433+00:00 - Information - 0 - MyConsumer - Updating for Product 42 <-- logs from the consumer code
 2023-06-06T09:30:41.7407242+00:00 - Information - 0 - MyConsumer - 0 modified for Product 42 <-- logs from the consumer code
 2023-06-06T09:30:41.7719252+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Messages - RECEIVE loopback://localhost/my-message-endpoint ff030000-ac11-0242-a321-08db6670b105 MyMessage MyConsumer(00:00:00.0734534)
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0018748+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Transports.BusDepot - Stopping bus instances: IBus
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0021543+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Stopping bus: loopback://localhost/
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0023811+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Stopping: loopback://localhost/my-message-endpoint
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0026290+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Completed: loopback://localhost/my-message-endpoint
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0026475+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Messages - Consumer Completed: loopback://localhost/my-message-endpoint: 1 received, 1 concurrent
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0026759+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Stopping: loopback://localhost/runnerwspzdzwlproject21928941concurrent0_testhost_bus_9hboyyfcnrbrfprdbdpschfqfb
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0027023+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit - Endpoint Completed: loopback://localhost/runnerwspzdzwlproject21928941concurrent0_testhost_bus_9hboyyfcnrbrfprdbdpschfqfb
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0027102+00:00 - Debug - 0 - MassTransit.Messages - Consumer Completed: loopback://localhost/runnerwspzdzwlproject21928941concurrent0_testhost_bus_9hboyyfcnrbrfprdbdpschfqfb: 0 received, 0 concurrent
 2023-06-06T09:30:42.0027993+00:00 - Information - 0 - MassTransit - Bus stopped: loopback://localhost/
```

The error is still on the same line:

```cs
await Harness.Bus.Publish(message);

(await Harness.Consumed.SelectAsync<TMessage>().Any()).Should().BeTrue(); // <- here

(await ConsumerHarness.Consumed.SelectAsync<TMessage>().Any()).Should().BeTrue();
```

**Expected (Harness.Consumed.SelectAsync().Any()) to be true, but found False.**

Any other ideas?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". The current title does not help readers know what the question is about, only what your opinion of MassTransit is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```cs
cfg.SetTestTimeouts(testInactivityTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

Or some larger value to account for the fact that your CI/CD box likely has significantly fewer CPU cores and less memory than your local box, and it just might be "busy."

For instance, if your consumer is slow to create the first time for some reason, or whatever, that initial delay might be cause.

#### UPDATED

The only other thing I see is that you aren't disposing of the service provider after the test. In the scenario where you are running multiple tests, it might be that something is getting in the way and causing to fail. No idea what, but not disposing of the service provider is a bad idea since it leaves all sorts of things in memory.

Comment: do you think that it is just a timeout, and not some kind of race condition? successful run of the test is much shorter. I will increase the timeout and hope that's enough, I will accept the answer if it doesn't fail within a week

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but the tests are still failing, I edited the question

Comment: seems like in the end this works. I had to change a saga test from fanning out 200 messages to 20 (sometime some messages got lost, but that's on in memory bus not being for production I guess). I also just went to docs and saw that there is a using statement for the service provider there - I suggest adding a comment or a section talking about disposing it, it's quite easy to miss, or even doing try/finally in the first example. Thanks a lot for help!